# nodemailer error when used self-signed cirtificate

Tags: node.js, openssl, nodemailer, starttls, self-signed-certificate

I am running an SMTP server using NodeMailer (smtp-server) module.
It is accepting all the incoming emails. Currently, it is using plain text mode, I want to use a self-signed certificate for the communication. I generated the certificate by following the instruction mentioned [here](https://www.virtualmin.com/node/12051) .

But it is giving error:

```
error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1550:SSL alert number 48
```

Create server object looks like below:

```js
const server = new SMTPServer({
  authMethods: ['PLAIN'],
  secure: false,
  authOptional: true,
  //hideSTARTTLS: true,
  key: fs.readFileSync('mydomain.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('mydomain.crt'),
  checkServerIdentity: () => { return null; },
  logger:true,
  onAuth(auth, session, callback) {
    ...
    ... 
  },
  onData(stream, session, callback) {
    ...
    ...
  }
});
```